# React-leaflet: add click and popup to KML layout

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, kml, react-leaflet

i 'm getting some Kml's from server (by axios) and loading them on map:

```
// functional Component KmlManager -> 

const map = useMap()

const addTrackAndBoundsFromKml = kmltext => {
 const parser = new DOMParser();
 var kml = parser.parseFromString(kmltext,"text/xml");
 const track = new L.KML(kml);
 map.addLayer(track);
};

React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('url')
      .then( res => {
             const allLayouts = res.data
             allLayouts.forEach(element => {addTrackAndBoundsFromKml(element.kml)})
    })
})
```

[**code above is using This approach**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/334008/input-multiple-kml-files-into-leaflet-api)

it is working fine and loading Kml's. but now I want to add click listener and popup to each Kml Layout.

i tried this for popup but no luck:

```
const track = new L.KML(kml).bindPupop("text of the popup");
```

could not figured out how to add `onclick`.

it it possible with this approach? Thanks!